# Debugging a Javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to debug this slideshow and I have understood everything except one thing which is **why when they replace or they add the `action` class they use spaces in the name as shown in the image below** I have searched on google (actually I didn't know what I have to type to get the right answer) so I tried to read about the className in Mdn and w3schools but with no result

[image]
here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <body>


        <div class="slider-container">
          <div class="mySlide fade">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" class="img">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlide fade">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="" class="img">
          </div>
          <div class="mySlide fade">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="" class="img">
            </div>
            <div class="btns">
              <span class="btn" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
              <span class="btn" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
              <span class="btn" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
            </div>
          </div>




<script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 666.656px;
  }
  .mySlide{
    max-width: 1000px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .btns{
    text-align: center;
  }
  .btn{
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #bbb;
margin: 0 2px;
  }
.active, .btn:hover{
  background-color: pink;
}
.fade{
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%{
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  100%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**Js**

```
var slideIndex=1;
showSlide(slideIndex);
function currentSlide(n){
  showSlide(slideIndex=n);
}
function showSlide(n){
  var i;
  var slides=document.getElementsByClassName("mySlide");
  var dotz=document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  for(i=0;i<slides.length;i++){
    slides[i].style.display="none";
  }
  for(i=0;i<dotz.length;i++){
    dotz[i].className=dotz[i].className.replace(" active","");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display="block";
  dotz[slideIndex-1].className+=" active";
}
```

Comment: they are using += to concatenate.  adding a space will make words such as Word1 Word2 Word3 rather than Word1Word2Word3 that way active can be added to the class if one already exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using `+=` to concatenate.  Adding a space will make words such as `Word1 Word2 Word3` rather than `Word1Word2Word3` that way active can be added to the class if one already exists.

For example you have this simple example:

if you add class active as `"active"` with `+=` it would be `class="testactive"` 
if you add active as `" active"` it would be `class="test active"` 
They do this so they can add a separate class.

You can view += [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment_2)